# "Currency" currency variable in virtual casino not working, instantly resets

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a virtual casino to practice with Javascript.  I already got the roulette wheel working, so now I wanted to add a "currency" feature. Basically, the player enters the casino with 200 dollars, and as he or she gambles, their currency amount changes.

Here's what I tried to do.  In the html part of the document, there is a sentence that reads "You currently have $200."  The 200 is enclosed in a div called "m."  The variable "money" then takes this number from that sentence/div.  When the player spins the roulette wheel, money is subtracted or added to the variable money and then the contents of the div "m" is changed accordingly.

What I'd hoped is that, after the player spun the wheel, that would rewrite the contents of div 'm', which would in turn change the variable "money."  However, this just doesn't work.  Here's a sample of the code:

```
var money = document.getElementById("m");

function spin(){
  var landing = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;   

  var nsvalue = parseInt(document.regular_roulette.num_select.value);

  var betvalue = parseInt(document.regular_roulette.bet.value);

  if (landing === nsvalue) {
    alert("You win $" + betvalue * 3);

    money = money + (betvalue * 3);
  } else {
    alert("You lose $" + betvalue);

    money = money - betvalue;
  }

  document.getElementById("m").innerText = money;
}

//why is it fleeting?  I've seen this before.
        </script>
</head>
<body>

    You currently have $<div id = "m">200</div>
```

Let's say the player bets 7 dollars.  What happens is div 'm' will flash with a number "-7" or "21" if, showing how much the player won or lost, and then immediately restore to being 200.  If I put a "parseInt()" around the assignment of the variable "money", that just causes it to flash "NaN."  Even if I ditch this concept and just put "var money = 200", it will flash "193" before returning to 200.

How do I make this work?  How do I have a currency variable that increases or decreases based on the results of a bet and can span multiple spins?

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `money` in the head of the document, which gets executed before the the `<div id="m">` is available. You are also setting the value to the element rather than the text in the element. As a result `money` is undefined.

You need to put that in an `onload` handler or right before the closing body tag.

I don't know how you are doing `document.regular_roulette`, so this just uses a static value, but it might help:

```js
var money

function spin() {
  var landing = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
  var nsvalue = parseInt(10);
  var betvalue = parseInt(10);
  if (landing === nsvalue) {
    document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "You win $" + betvalue * 3
    money = money + (betvalue * 3);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('alert').innerHTML = "You lose $" + betvalue
    money = money - betvalue;
  }
  document.getElementById("m").innerText = money;
}
window.onload = function() {
  money = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").innerText);
}
```

```html
You currently have $
<div id="m">200</div>
<div id="alert"></div>
<button onclick="spin()">spin</button>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, where do I put the onload handler?

Comment: @DennisMarkham I added an example. If this were mine, I would set a set the money in the javascript and the add it to the div rather than reading it from the div — but that's a different question.